# Форматирование срок. Полная замена одной строки другой строкой с сохранением числа символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

К примеру, есть начальная строка из **n-го** количества символов:

> "my secret code i want to secure"

И у меня есть ключевое слово:

> "password"

Как форматировать первую строку так, чтобы она стала выглядеть следующим образом:

```
 'passwordpasswordpasswordpasswor'
```

**Число символов ровняется n включая пробелы**

Единственное, что приходит на ум, так это умножить вторую строку некоторое кол-во раз, а после просто сделать срез по `len` первой строки. Но это не выход.

Comment: *Но это не выход.* - почему?

Comment: Почему не выход?? (pwd * (len(string_) // len(pwd) + 1))[:len(string_)]

Comment: `from itertools import cycle; enc = "".join(key for key, plain in zip(cycle(password), text))`.

Comment: `enc = "".join(password[i%len(password)] for i in range(len(text)))`.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: Шифр Фейстеля делаешь?

Comment: вам дали уже 2 ответа, мб какой нибудь подошел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
x = 'asdfasdfsadfasdfsadfafasfasdfsadf'
y = 'dicky'

new_str = ''
for i in range(len(x)):
    new_str += y[i % len(y)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего, тут надо посчитать количество букв в фразе, а затем вывести слово password столько раз, чтобы букв было столько же.
Вот код

```
string = input("Ведите строку ")
key = "password"
count = (len(string) / len(key)) * len(key)
for i in range(int(count)):
    print(key[i % len(key)], end='')
```

Comment: посчитай, сколько букв твоей фразе. Обрати внимание, что последнее слово    password вывелось не до конца, потому что в исходной фразе 31 буква, а в слове password 8 букв.

Comment: Надеюсь, сейчас нет вопросов?

Comment: сейчас вопросов нет)

Comment: я думал, что человеку нужна подсказка, так сказать толчок, а тут оказывается нужны лишь готовые ответы.

Comment: не обязательно готовые ответы. Но ответ должен помогать, а не повторять идею автора вопроса или идеи других отвечающих...